# Docker Compose - Shorter Aliases for Commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a rails application containerised using `docker` and `docker-compose` with `production` and `development` environments. Each environment has its own `.env` and `docker-compose.yml` files (inheriting from a common `compose` file, only redefining the `env-file` attribute).

So, to build the application in `development` mode:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml --env-file .env.development build
```

And a similar command for production. I'd like to create an alias to shorten this command as it becomes especially annoying when trying to run `rake` tasks. I'd prefer to not modify `~/.bashrc` (so other collaborators can use the aliases without having to follow a similar process).

Is there a better solution than shell scripts?

I should say that this is really a non-issue, it would just be nice to build my image using something like `app:dev build` - similar to how it's done using Node.js.

Comment: why not to implement a rake task for that command?

Comment: @Mr. I would still need to prefix it with the compose files and the env file

Comment: isn't it enough to provide the environment name as an argument to the rake command, which will give you the indication which environment files to load...

Comment: @Mr. Could you share an example? Also, that does not help with shortening my `docker-compose` commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to leverage a `Makefile` instead of a `rake` task (as suggested by @Mr.):

```
all: build.prod up.prod
build.dev:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml --env-file .env.dev build
build.prod:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml --env-file .env.prod build
up.dev:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml --env-file .env.dev up
up.prod:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml --env-file .env.prod up
down:
    docker-compose down
test:
    docker-compose --env-file .env.dev exec web rspec
bash.dev:
    docker-compose --env-file .env.dev exec web sh
bash.prod:
    docker-compose --env-file .env.prod exec web sh
dev: build.dev up.dev
```

And it gives the functionality I desire

Answer (score 0):

> Each environment has its own `.env` and `docker-compose.yml`

if you differentiate between each environment files by the environment name, then you can use a rake task as follows

```rb
namespace :docker do
  task :build, :env do |tsk, args|
    `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.#{args.env}.yml --env-file .env.#{args.env} build`
  end
end
```

now you can just simply run `rake docker:build[production]`.

note that, i did not test the code.